# DFS Replication across Hyper-V servers - duplicate GUID's

Tags: windows-server-2003, hyper-v, dfs-r

4 Hyper-V instances of Win2003 Server with 2 VHD's each (All based on same Win2003 VHD that i copied 4 times, everything seems to run just fine)

Trying to use DFS replication to keep some folders in sync but it fails with an error saying that a duplicate GUID has been detected. 
I understand the error as the VHD's are copies of each other, but is there some tools that I can use to change the GUID on a VHD drive?

Comment: where these domain joined prior to cloning if so then I'd sysprep then copy the resultant vhd file.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: Copying VHD files without running sysprep on them to reinitialize the Windows system to a new SID causes problems. You can copy the VHD files, but you need to sysprep / them.

Answer (score -1):

Simple answer, why not just create another VHD and do a software mirror on one of the machines? Once the synchronization is complete, dump the VHD that matches the one on the other machine.